# MyBatis: IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value

Tags: java, mybatis

I tried to code MyBatis but encounter IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value. Could anyone please tell me what wrong.

```
public interface StudentMapper {

    @Select("SELECT ID, Name, Address, Email FROM Student")
    @Results(value = {@Result(property="id", column="ID"),
        @Result(property="name", column="Name"),
        @Result(property="address", column="Address"),
        @Result(property="email", column="Email")})
    public ArrayList<Student> getStudent();

}
```

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("SqlMapConfig.xml");
        SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);

        try (SqlSession session =  sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
            List<Student> student = session.selectList("getStudent");

            for(Student st : student ){
                System.out.println(st.getId());
                System.out.println(st.getName());
                System.out.println(st.getEmail());
            }

            System.out.println("Records Read Successfully ");
            //session.commit();
            //session.close();
        }
```

Configuration located at resources folder:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>

    <environments default = "development">
        <environment id = "development">
            <transactionManager type = "JDBC"/>

            <dataSource type = "POOLED">
                <property name = "driver" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Student"/>
                <property name = "username" value = "root"/>
                <property name = "password" value = "1234"/>
            </dataSource>

        </environment>
    </environments>

    <!--<mappers>
        <mapper resource = "mapper.xml"/>
    </mappers>
 -->

</configuration>
```

Please help me as im stuck with it.

Comment: You need to register the mapper in the config i.e. `<mapper class="pkg.StudentMapper" />` (replace 'pkg' with the actual package name).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by add mapper with correct namespace.